# "ClassLib1" targets 'net.4.7.2' it cannot be referenced by a project that targets 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-framework-version

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65sOo.png)

Since the library I need to use supports minimum 4.7.2, I create a separate classlib for this case, because all classlibs I already have 3.5. but I cannot reference by targets 3.5

I think my last way is to create a console app for the process I need and trigger it when I need, but this is not a good idea..

What is the best way to solve this problem? Is there a way to get a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: upgrade your project to .net framework 4.7.2 or later

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution without upgrading

Comment: thats your only option. .net 3.5 is far out of support

Answer (score 0):

When people create a library, they used some new techniques from the newer version of dotnet that can't work with the older version.

So, for your question, in short: No way.

Long: Maybe yes, but it's complicated.

Eg: You have

- Project X based on .NET 3.5
- Library L requires minimal run on .NET 4.7.2

So. You can create a project Y run on .NET 4.7.2 and use the library.

Then, try to communicate between Project X and Y via Socket. They can talk to each other so that project X can use the feature from the library L.

Comment: if it is ui components then that won't work.